# Calculate Regular Polygon Arc Interior Angle with Known Number of Sides, Side Length and Chord Length

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A 6-sided arc from a regular polygon with 24 sides of 2.1m and a chord length of 11.4m has a [calculated interior angle](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/regular-polygon?v=hide:0,n_sides:24,a:210!cm) of 165° (ie 180 - 360/24).

How is the new interior angle calculated if the 2.1m arc sides are stretched over a 12m chord?

[image]

Comment: I understand there is no solution and it must be calculated iteratively.

Comment: The "6-sided arc from a regular polygon with 24 sides of 2.1m" is already over 12 m before stretching?

Comment: From the question, the chord length is 11.4 m, and the "6-sided arc" would have a length of $6\times 2.1 = 12.6\text{ m}$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Does the edit clarify the question?

Comment: Then each side would be stretched over $2.1\cdot 12/11.4\text{ m}$, and the interior angles are unchanged?

Comment: The side length remains 2.1m so the angle must change. Arc is longer and flatter.